# Prove $T ^ {n} = T_ {1} + ... + T_ {k}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V $ complex inner product space (real) with $\dim V = n$ and let $T $  normal nonzero operator (symmetric) on $V$. Show that there are $k$ operators $T_1, ... T_k: k \le n$ on $V$ such that $T_i \ne T_j$ if $i \ne j$ and for every positive integer $n$

$T ^ {n} = T_ {1} + ... + T_ {k}$

Thanks for your help.

Have a nice day

Comment: You have $\dim V = n$, and later 'for every positive integer $n$'?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Is $V$ a real or complex inner product space? Is $T$ just normal or is it self-adjoint? And why can't you just take $k=1$ and $T_1=T^n$? Are there any requirements on the $T_i$s?

Comment: So you're saying that $T_1+\cdots+T_k=T^m$ for *every* $m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for k = n. You can forexample let $T_i$ be projection onto the i^'th orthogonal eigenvector multiplied with $\lambda_i^n$, that is $T_i(u_j) = \lambda_i^n u_j $ if $i = j$ and it's $0$ otherwise. Where $\lambda_i$ is the t'th eigenvalue of $T$.

**Added:** On matrix form the operator $T_1$ becomes  $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_1^n k_1 u_1 & \lambda_1^n k_2 u_1 & \ldots &  k_n\lambda_1^n u_1\\
\end{array}
\right]$ Where the k_j^s are such that if $U \left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\end{array}
\right]=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0 \\
\vdots\\
1\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{array}
\right]
= e_j
$. Then $x_1 = k_j$, where $U$ is ofcourse the matrix with i'th column $u_i$.  For $T_i$ do the same but change the 1's with i's.

I guess that the reason for $k \le n$ is that $0$ might be an eigenvalue, in which case we can/must drop some of the $T_i$'s.